# Why are there so many definitions of database?

Tags: database-theory, dbms

In my lecture today, I heard that a database is a collection of related data that is organized.

From Google I came across these:

*"A database is a collection of data, typically describing the activities of one or more related organizations."*

*"A database is an organized collection of data."*

*"A database is a collection of information that is organized so that it can easily be accessed, managed, and updated."*

Why does everyone seem to came up with their own definition? Why is it not fixed? How do I make up my mind which one to accept?

These definitions doesn't say the data is "related" from what I heard in lecture. So I am very confused.

Comment: "Why is it not fixed?" by who? Who has the authority to fix the meaning of English phrases and say this is the one true definition that we all should be using from now on?

Comment: Why do you think they're different?

Answer (score 4):

If you compare any two [authorative](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dictionary) [references](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dictionary) for a single subject they will employ different words even though they convey the same meaning. This is just the nature of English - it has a very rich and overlapping vocabulary, accumulated from many sources over centuries.

Looking at the examples listed in the question they all contain the concepts of data, collection and organization. To me they seem to be describing the same thing, even if they describe it in different ways.

As used specifically in digital technology the term "database" covers a great many things. An IMS hierarchical database looks very different to a relational database, which is different again to a sharded, clustered JSON document store. Yet all these products use the same word to describe one tier of their offering. Writing a set of words that covers the usage these technologies make of the word "database" would be impossible. Yet all of them allow the *collection* and *organization* of *data*, so meet the definitons listed.

Answer (score 1):

The term "related" is relative. Logically, nobody would seriously want to go to the effort of storing a whole bunch of unrelated facts - although it is possible to do, even using an RDBMS.

The term "relational" in an RDBMS is a mathematical concept as outlined [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)).

Perhaps, on this forum, a better question might be: I have such and such a collection of data - how do I put it into a database?